# Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Credentials

Tags: http, cors

I have a common authentication form across multiple subdomains (example.com, blog.example.com, and app.example.com). The login form must submit this data to example.com irrespective of where it is shown, so I thought of using CORS, but this:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com http://blog.example.com http://app.example.com")
```

[does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

So I thought of doing the next thing, and checking the Origin header manually on server side, and allowing a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` so that requests might be made, but unfortunately, this crops up [in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials)

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

Is there any way to make my request work across multiple domains, and still send credentials using CORS ?

Comment: I believe you can also put commas between the domain names. (i.e. so, yes, you can make it work across multiple domains.)

Comment: I don't think so. From the spec:

>In practice the origin-list-or-null production is more constrained. Rather than allowing a space-separated list of origins, it is either a single origin or the string "null". [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1) are you also including the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" header? This is needed for passing cookie credentials (and the corresponding XHR client must set .withCredentials = true)

2) Have you tried the suggestion from your link and only include the origin for the current request. For example, if a request comes in with the header "Origin: http://blog.example.com", you would respond with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://blog.example.com", and not a list of origins. This requires a little more work on your server side implementation.

3) One other thought, you mention that you have a single login form that must be shared by various domains. Well, if it is a standard HTML form, you can do a regular form-post across domains. You don't need to use CORS. Just set the "action" property of the form to the url you wish to post to. For example:

```
<form name="login" action="http://login.example.com/doLogin">
```

Comment: I ended up using (2). Somehow I had overlooked the single origin method.

Answer (score 2):

```
// cross domain
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: Don't do that without a strict verification of the Origin header or you will open security hole

Comment: This answer illustrates why it's impossible to have fool-proof security -- in technicolor even!! >.<

Comment: OK appears that this is "in essence" the same as doing "*" which can open up subtle security holes so is discouraged, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Why not do this: http://blog.portswigger.net/2016/10/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for.html