# Javascript Testing Webservice Locally - CORS

Tags: javascript, android, web-services

I'm attempting to build a jQuery mobile application locally that connect to my website via XMLHttpRequest/XCRF/JSON. When attempting to connect to my website I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wwws.mydomain.com/rest/system/connect. 
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm enabled CORS on my webserver (mydomain.com) per CORS documentation:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

How can I test my webservice from outside of my website? When this is converted to an Android app will I have similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of security, you cannot do that. If you want to allow credentials then your Access-Control-Allow-Origin must not use *.

Check out these thread:
[Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074665/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-credentials)

Comment: This is fine, I can set the domain manually but will this affect a Phonegap project and how it connects?