# ng2-file-upload access-control origin issue

Tags: angular, file-upload

I have used this library for angular2 file upload https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

Now I'm getting this error when I upload a file

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/files. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: this solved the same issue of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/47334113/5236174 , please check if it is an acceptable answer in your case.

Answer (score 32):

Make `withCredentials = false` before uploading the item. You can put this code in `ngOnInit`/ `constructor` or `ngOnChanges`.

```
this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item) => {
  item.withCredentials = false;
}
```

Comment: If I could upvote 100 times I would do that, This saved my frustration of google storage upload from past two days.

Comment: i've been looking for this solution for long time. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your server is responding with the following `CORS Header`

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' = true
```

This is a security that `CORS` provide, you are not allowed to do that. You cannot use  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` =  * if you what to allow credentials. You will have to specify the exact domain. try Specifying

```
localhost:<portnumber>
```

For more information look at the following links

1. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and
   protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols)
2. [Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074665/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-credentials)
3. [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754/756987)

Comment: i have added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" this one

Comment: you cannot use it, in your header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is coming as `true` which doesn't not allow you to use , `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as `*`.

Specify an exact origin `localhost:3000` or some how set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` as false

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (item => {
      item.withCredentials = false;
   });
}
```