# file uploading has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, file, upload

I am trying file upload via angular **ng2-file upload** .

I have 2 local server :

**http://localhost:4200 for angular**   and **http://localhost that provide php files**

when i send file to php server for upload get error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296349/ng2-file-upload-access-control-origin-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following headers in your php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```